# Is there a .net function to enumerate the language fallback file extensions

Tags: c#, .net, resx

My application will be translated into several languages.

I can include strings for the various supported language (strings.fr-BE.resx, strings.nl.resx etc).

I also have some external files (myfile.nl.txt etc) that also need to be picked up in the same way, including fallback if not found.

Obviously, I can write a fairly simple function to enumerate the language extensions, from the selected language (MyFile.fr-BE.tx -> MyFile.fr.txt -> MyFile.txt), but wondered if any part of this mechanism is exposed by the .net framework, so I can re-use the existing convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in that I'm aware of but it's easy enough to construct once you're aware of the [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) property of [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static class CultureInfoExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<CultureInfo> WithParents(this CultureInfo culture)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return culture;
            if (culture.Parent == culture) yield break;
            culture = culture.Parent;
        }

    }
}
```

And testing:

```
var test = new CultureInfo("fr-BE");
foreach(var culture in test.WithParents())
{
    Console.WriteLine(culture);
}
```

Yields:

```
    fr-BE
    fr
```

(The last line being the empty string)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Parent property.  That's really helpful, thank Damien.